# Returning Row number after filter VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way I can select or return the cell address of the first visible cell after filtering? I have this so far, and stuck in selecting the first visible cell after filter.

```
fileSheet.Name = "Test"

With fileSheet
    .Range("A2").Activate
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=">1"
    'select the first visible cell after column header
End With
```

I actually have column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim firstCell as Range
set firstCell = fileSheet.usedRange.offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1)
```

`UsedRange` returns the range of the sheet in use (okay, sometimes too much but that doesn't matter in this case), `offset(1, 0)` moves one line down so that the headerlines are ignored, `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` gets a list of all cells that are visible and therefore the last `(1)` returns the first visible cell.

Answer (score 0):

With given range as `A1`, this would give you the first visible cell:

```
Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row
```

1. Offset will skip the header row
2. SpecialCells will move control to visible cells.
3. Pick first item from the visible cells.
4. Find Row

Comment: `.Offset` returns `Method or data member not found` error.

Comment: @ramedju, it was a typo, fixed.

Comment: For me every time row number returning as 1.
My excel filtered from row 2 that is A2, and first visible row after applying filter is A183. But when I am using above formula, I am getting row number as 1.
Dim FR As Long
    FR = Range("A2").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lastrow=cells(rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row 
  For x=1 To lastrow 
    If cells(x,"A")=criteria1 Then 
       rowfound=x 
     endif 
   Next x
```

Dim the variables at the start

Comment: The other 2 answers are much easier (better). This is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code if you want to pick the first row after filter, I have try it

Code:

```
activesheet.AutoFilter.Range.offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).select
```