# Set VBA variable to value of AutoFiltered cell

Tags: vba, variables, collections, autofilter

After applying an AutoFilter to a column, I receive my filtered results. I then use the FillDown method to populate a different column. Using the FillDown method leaves me with an ActiveCell Range. I need to set the value of the first cell of the ActiveCell Range (The cell used to populate the empty cells via FillDown) to a variable. I've gotten it to work with the following code in a separate Module:

```
Variable1 = ActiveCell.Range("A1").Value
```

However, when I then insert this into my production For Loop that cycles through a collection, it does not assign the value of the first filtered cell to my Variable1 variable. Setting a Watch for Variable1 always reports empty. Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

```
For Each Item In UItem
Workbooks("Data.csv").Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=UItem.Item(Item)
        Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=8).Select
        ActiveCell.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.FillDown
        Variable1 = ActiveCell.Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: You can `Select` many cells. That's the `Selection`. Within any `Selection` one cell is the `ActiveCell`. That's always a single cell. `Selection.Cells(1, 1)` specifies the first cell of the selected range (`Selection(Cells(1)` does the same job and is preferrable if the range has only a single column. Since *ActiveCell* is always a single cell, `ActiveCell.Cells(1,1)` is the same as `ActiveCell`.  `Cells(1,1)` is the same as `Range("A1")`. Prefer the former when addressing single cells. ... And then avoid selecting anything. Use the `Range` object instead of the `Selection` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the ActiveCell property returns a Range object that represents the cell that is active, therefore, 1 unique cell once is declared active using `.Activate`. In your code this always happened to be `"A1"`

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Activate
(...)
Variable1 = ActiveCell.Value
```

Will always assign the value of `.Range("A1")` to `Variable1`. Now, if what you are looking for is to get the first visible filtered value, this will not necessarily be your ActiveCell. I would look into using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` here a useful post for it [Returning Row number after filter VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759474/returning-row-number-after-filter-vba)

Comment: I've tried many .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) variations with no success, for example: Item1 = ActiveCell.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Value
Item1 = ActiveCell.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
Item1 = ActiveCell.Range("A1:A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

Comment: I believe that what you want is to store into 'variable1' the first visible value of the column 8 which you used to ```.FillDown``` if that is the case in your code after ```Selection.FillDown```  do ```Variable1 = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1)```